# bootstrap modal insert form submit won't reset to add another entry

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, insert, modal-dialog

I am using php mysql to insert to the database and that was working, however the bootstrap modal won't let me submitting another item. The button still says inserting and the last inserted data is still showing in the inputs.

I want to insert multiple times as this becomes part of a larger edit form.
This is put outside of the edit form submit button:

```
 <div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
 <h4 class="modal-title">Add A New Item</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <form method="post" id="insert_form">
 <input type="hidden" name="job_id" id="job_id" value="<?php echo $job_id;?>">
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="job_mat_qty" name="job_mat_qty" value="1"  />
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="job_mat_desc" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
 <textarea class="form-control editors" id="job_mat_desc"  name="job_mat_desc" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter item title and / or description" />
 </textarea>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="job_mat_cost" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
 <div class="input-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
 <input type="text" class="form-control calculate invoice_product_price txt" autocomplete="off" id="job_mat_cost" name="job_mat_cost" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="0.00"  />
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-10"> </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<input type="submit" name="insert" id="selected" value="Insert"     class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>


$(document).on('click', '.delete-rows', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Item?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "job_remove_material_new.php",
                data: ({
                    id: id
                }),
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $(".delete_mem" + id).fadeOut('slow');
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });



  $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
  event.preventDefault(); 

  if($('#job_mat_desc').val() == "")  
  {  
  alert("Description is required");  
  }  

  else  
  {  
  $.ajax({  
  url:"add_material.php",  
  method:"POST",  
  data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),
  cache: false,  
  beforeSend:function(){  
  $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
  },  
  success:function(data){  
  $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
  $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide'); 
  $('#invoice_table').html(data);  
  }  

 });  
 $(function () {

 $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#add_data_Modal", function () {
 $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
 });
 });
 }  
 });
```

Sorry I have no clue how to add this code correctly for this forum so please be kind....
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this

```
  $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
  event.preventDefault(); 

  if($('#job_mat_desc').val() == "")  
  {  
  alert("Description is required");  
  }  

  else  
  {  
  $.ajax({  
  url:"add_material.php",  
  method:"POST",  
  data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),
  cache: false,  
  beforeSend:function(){  
  $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
  },  
  success:function(data){  
  //$('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
  $('#insert_form input[type="text"],textarea').val(''); // here is change
  $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide'); 
  $('#invoice_table').html(data);  
  }  

 });
```

In my case it will work successfully so I hope it will help you

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply, I tried it but it removes the submit button on inserting a new item. I did change it to have this above that code but it removes the price input but not the textarea:`code`$('#add_data_Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
        $(':textarea', '#insert_form').val("");
    });`code`

Comment: Thank you so much that works really well, the only thing I had to change was instead of .html(data) I put .prepend(data)

Comment: Oh gee now it won't output on the page as I enter them. Not sure what happened. It doesn't work if I use $('#invoice_table').html(data); nor for $('#invoice_table').prepend(data);  or $('#invoice_table').apend(data);